# unity3d запись переменной в UI другой сцены

Tags: c#, unity3d

как записать в **UItext** очки, набранные в другой сцене?То есть переменную скрипта записать в **UItext** в другой сцене.

Comment: А вам разве не советовали сделать класс со стачическими переменными?

Comment: Спасибо, советовали. Почему то не получается. Объявил вот таким образом: public static  int score = 0; Теперь мне нужно эту переменную получить в другой сцене. Чтобы :  mycount.text = score.ToString();Она не видна в другой сцене.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторый поступают следующим образом: создают отдельный прифаб для всего на всю игру. В нем могут храниться очки, жизни, какие-то текстуры, графика, музыка и прочее прочее, что является общим для всех сцен. Называют данный прифаб, к примеру `GameManager`. А далее таскают этот прифаб от сцены к сцены с помощью функции [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) - это значит, что объект не удаляется при загрузке новой сцены.

Выглядит код так:

```
 void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
 }
```

Чтобы узнать, что загрузилась новая сцена (за исключением нулевой дефолтной), можно использовать метод [OnLevelWasLoaded](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html)

В итоге будет прифаб `GameManager` в нем скрипт со всем необходимым, допустим тоже будет называться `GameManagerScript`, в котором будет поле с очками и прочим необходимым и методами `DontDestroyOnLoad` и `OnLevelWasLoaded`.

В процессе игры очки либо сразу заносить в тот скрипт, либо же при переходе на другую сцену брать очки из другого скрипта и заносить в переменную `points` Гейм менеджера.

На следующей сцене в методе `OnLevelWasLoaded` пишем инструкции, чтоб взять значение из переменной `points` и поместила туда, куда вам необходимо, в тот же UI.text, к примеру.

Примерно так:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManagerScript: MonoBehaviour {
    public static int points = 100;

    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);        
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
         Text ui =  GameObject.Find("/Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
         Debug.Log("scene was loaded");
    }
}
```

Желательно этот скрипт сделать синглтоном, во избежании дублирования. Примерно так получится:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManagerScript: MonoBehaviour {
public static GameManagerScript instance;
    public static int points = 100;

    void Awake() {
    if (!instance) {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    } else {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }            
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
         Text ui =  GameObject.Find("/Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
         Debug.Log("scene was loaded");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения и код. Нулевая сцена - начало игры. Кнопка старт переводит на след.сцену, где собственно и ведется счет. Префаб следует создать здесь? И на него повесить скрипт с подсчетом, так? Отдельным скриптом делаю его DontDestroyOnLoad .Либо не так понял, либо криво сделал. Не работает.

Comment: @Georgich Надо создать пустой объект, сделать его префабом... написать сий скрипт.. накинуть его сразу на тот самый префаб и можно сразу на нулевую сцену кинуть и дальше он сам  уже по следующим сценам подхватываться будет.......не работает в чем выражается? ошибки есть какие-нибудь? ......наглядное видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY2WB28I_X8

Comment: спасибо.Мне показалось, на видео переключают сцены кнопками, и вроде это все.

Comment: насчет кода, никаких ошибок. Просто не работает. Не переносит ничего в другую сцену.Повесил на Empty скрипт со счетом, чтобы счет был доступен в другой сцене. Повесил на него ваш скрипт и после этого сделал его префабом.Закинул префаб в обе сцены. Ничего не переносится.

Comment: @Georgich **на обе сцены не надо ничего кидать**... ТОЛЬКО на первоначальную, с чего игра начинается..........в видео доступно показано что создается `SceneManager` (если обратите внимание - его нет на второй сцене) и он переносится с первой сцены на вторую при клике на кнопку.....

Comment: спасибо. Что то сдвинулось. SceneManager переходит в другую сцену, и данные в нем есть, забрать их не смог.

Comment: Алексей, большое спасибо, все получилось

Answer (score 1):

Просто хочу сказать, что [в вики Unity3d уже есть синглтон.](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton)
Дабы избежать велосипедостроения :З