# Проблемы с передачей функций и параметров

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь передать функцию GameManager в объект. Выдает ошибку:  "Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". Подскажите, пожалуйста,что делаю не так.

```
if (transform.position.y < -0.01f)
{
     gameObject.SetActive(false);
     GameManager.PlusObj();
}
```

Собственно сама функция:

```
public void PlusObj() 
{
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обращении к методу вот так:

```
GameManager.PlusObj();
```

Необходимо, чтобы метод `PlusObj` был статическим. В ином случае надо делать вот так:

```
GameManager gm = new GameManager();
gm.PlusObj();
```

---

Если GameManager - компонент, а не просто класс (от mono behaviour) то инстанс надо делать не через new а через `GetComponent`. Или вообще для начала надо найти сам компонент на сцене через `FindObjectsOfType`.

А вообще менеджер надо делать синглтоном: см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491737/191482
и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513205/191482
и работать уже с его инстансом

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так и все сработало:

```
public GameManager gm;
void Start () 
{
    gm = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
}
```